# PHP echo a A multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that like this:
I can use array_column then echo **items**
but how can I echo **article_id** from tracking_details. thank you very much

```
  "order_id": "AP38383755",
  "order_creation_date": "2021-02-10T21:09:34+11:00",
  "order_summary": {
    "total_cost": 14.59,
    "total_cost_ex_gst": 13.26,
    "total_gst": 1.33,
    "status": "Delivered",
  },
  "shipments": [
    {

      "shipment_id": "0DMK0EGT5d8AAAF3RCwdeItp",
      "items": [
        {
          "tracking_details": {
            "article_id": "123456",
            "barcode_id": "789456"
          },
        },
      ],


    },
    {
      "shipment_id": "0DMK0EGT5d8AAAF3RCwdeItp",
      "items": [
        {
          "tracking_details": {
            "article_id": "123456",
            "barcode_id": "789456"
          },
        },
      ],
    }
    ]
```

I know it's a json, i just want to know how php can echo this article_id from an array.

[PIC FOR ARRAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlT4m.png)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what detail you actually want? If it's simply the `article_id` then something like a simple loop should work:

```
$json = '{"order_id":"AP38383755","order_creation_date":"2021-02-10T21:09:34+11:00","order_summary":{"total_cost":14.59,"total_cost_ex_gst":13.26,"total_gst":1.33,"status":"Delivered"},"shipments":[{"shipment_id":"0DMK0EGT5d8AAAF3RCwdeItp","items":[{"tracking_details":{"article_id":"123456","barcode_id":"789456"}}]},{"shipment_id":"0DMK0EGT5d8AAAF3RCwdeItp","items":[{"tracking_details":{"article_id":"123456","barcode_id":"789456"}}]}]}';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($arr["shipments"] as $a) {
    echo $a["items"][0]["tracking_details"]["article_id"];
}
```